# What is the good way to get user_id from user home folder

Tags: plone

I'm making an "Author information" portlet showing information of a member when we are in user's home folder, ie: when the request url is http://.../Plone/Members/user1/*, the portlet needs to know user_id is user1.

What is the good way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the owner of the folder:

```py
from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import getSecurityManager

owner = folder.getOwner()
user = getSecurityManager().getUser()

if owner is user:
     return True # show the portlet
```